# Вводное слово или союз? Как обособить "а следовательно"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, союзы

*Ты владеешь стихиями. Двери символизируют собой стихии, а следовательно ты имеешь к ним доступ.*

Если "следовательно" имеет значения "поэтому", то является союзом и не требует после себя запятой. А если в значении "таким образом", то обособляется с обеих сторон, так как является вводным словом.

Answer (score 2):

Ты владеешь стихиями. *Двери символизируют собой стихии, **а следовательно,** ты имеешь к ним доступ.*

Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП). ***А следовательно*** ― единая конструкция, включающая сочинительный союз А и вводное слово  ***следовательно***. Такое сочетание обособляется, если союз А относится именно к вводному слову.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пункт 5.  Если же изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, то запятая после сочинительного союза не ставится (обычно при союзе а):  Расчёты были сделаны наскоро, **а следовательно,** и неточно;

**Примеры**

Следственный комитет решение суда не получал, **а следовательно,** необходимо продлить сроки на обжалование, что и было сделано.  [«Совершенно секретно», 2003.09.01]

Судя по финской кепке, можно было сказать, что человеку этому не чужды веянья моды, **а следовательно,** и модные веянья.  [Фазиль Искандер. Путь из варяг в греки (1990)]

Comment: Простите, Sharon, что дал менее подробный ответ после вашего с таким же смыслом. Просто уже начал писать тогда, и было обидно всё стирать.

Comment: Пишите дальше, Артем, ответ мне не кажется теперь очевидным, как бы не пришлось корректировать.

Comment: *А что смутило?*

Comment: Тут  у Розенталя в тексте, кажется, есть опечатка. У него в одной и той же конструкции (однородные члены)  запятая то ставится, то нет, прочитайте пункт 5 до конца: (1) Расчёты были сделаны наскоро, а следовательно, и неточно; (2) Эта схема, а следовательно и весь проект в целом нуждается в проверке. Пропущена запятая?

Comment: @Sharon, мне кажется, что я немного не точно объяснила вопрос. Грамота.ру дает такое правило:СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, вводное слово и союз
1. Вводное слово. Указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения; то же, что «стало быть», «таким образом».
2. Союз. То же, что «и поэтому, а значит». Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «следовательно», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.Я – русский человек, следовательно имею право это сказать.

Comment: Nara, я справочник тоже прочитала, и как раз по нему задала сейчас вопрос (думаю, что не вся информация в нем правильная).  А Ваше предложение я решаю по правилам Розенталя (вот только там, кажется, есть опечатка). Также я учитываю тексты в Нацкорпусе,  где "а следовательно", все обособляют (впрочем, как и "следовательно" все обособляют тоже). "Следовательно" может быть союзом только по отношению к обособленным оборотам, если решать задачу по классическим правилам.

Comment: Sharon, вот здесь запятые стоят: https://studopedia.su/15_82155_obshchie-pravila-postanovki-znakov-prepinaniya-pri-vvodnih-slovah-sochetaniyah-i-predlozheniyah.html И здесь тоже: https://polplu2402.ucoz.ru/index/vvodnye_slova/0-113

Comment: Римма, ну да, всё верно, но вы согласны, что у Розенталя опечатка?

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо вам, что даете такое четкое объяснение. А то я так и была бы в неведении...

Comment: Nara, Вы же сами все написали в комментарии. У Вас не "следовательно", а "а следовательно". Подставьте значения союза, получится "а и поэтому" или "а а значит".

Comment: @Sharon Да, считаю, что это опечатка.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, вы правы, но а если без "а"?

Comment: У вас в предложении два "действующих лица" (не как в примере). Я бы поставила запятую.

Comment: Согласен насчёт действующих лиц.

Comment: Артем, какие действующие лица вы обсуждаете? Может быть, вы хотите сказать, что это сложное предложение, а не предложение с однородными членами? Так в справочнике речь идет о синтаксических конструкциях вообще, а в словаре приводятся примеры сложных предложений без запятой: "Свет горит, следовательно родители ещё не спят".   Так что, будете обособлять вводное слово в сложном предложении? Это правилам вроде бы не соответствует. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь у *"а следовательно"* напрашивается смысл *"а стало быть",* поэтому это *вводное слово.* Союз *"а"* привязан скорее к нему, чем к продолжению *"ты имеешь".* Поэтому запятую лучше поставить одну *после "следовательно".*

Comment: но  мне кажется, здесь значение "поэтому"